# How to protect my Javascript from being accessed by other parties?

Tags: javascript, ajax, security

Simply put, I have a website with a Javascript library which includes ads through a script tag. Now I'm concerned that the implemented ads can access my Javascript library (also included through a script tag), which does Ajax calls to a server (on which the user has a session).

I am looking to guard my Javascript from influence of included Javascript of the ads, as I don't want the ad companies to be able to make Ajax calls. In doing this, I don't want to rely to serverside scripting outside my Javascript library (note that calls to the library cannot have serverside scripting) (although setting a htpasswd is possible i.e.).

An example would be:

Library.js (can have serverside scripting, an other domain)

```
var library = function(parameters) {
      return ajaxCallWithParameters(parameters);
}
```

Website Javascript: (cannot rely on serverside scripting)

```
toTable(library());
```

Included possibly malicious ads: (other domain)

```
sendToAdServer(library());
```

In the case of using serverside scripting I could simply do:

```
   <script>var <?php echo $somehowSyncedrandomByTime; ?> = function(parameters) {
          return ajaxCallWithParameters(parameters);
    }</script> <!-- included JS script of other domain which supplies AJAX -->

    <script>toTable(<?php echo $somehowSyncedrandomByTime; ?>());</script> <!-- current domain -->

    <script>sendToAdServer(???());</script> <!-- by including offsite ad script -->
```

This way, the ads cannot find the function in question. But the website cannot include serverside scripting, so I am looking for an alternative.

**Is it possible to obscure my Javascript in a way that included Javascript from third parties cannot call/read it?**

Comment: Can you put the ads in an iframe?

Comment: If you don't trust Advertisers' JS enough to let it near your JS, then you can't trust it enough to let it anywhere near your site at all.

Comment: The ads can be put in an iframe, although since they're post on the same domain, I take it the ads would still have access indirectly.

Comment: The ads load through a <script> tag?

Comment: Yes, the ads load through a script tag.

Comment: Well; then they are "your" ads.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Frankly, no, it's not possible to somehow obscure or protect your scripts against other scripts *running in the same context/scope* as yours. But you always have the possibility to lock third party scripts in an `iframe` - i.e., they won't be able to interact with your code in any way unless you provide an interface (e.g. social networks use this a lot).

Comment: Would the Iframes page have to be on another domain? Couldn't I use parent.document.library() else for example?

Comment: Well, yes, as long as iframes reside on the same domain, they will have access. You could try to stop those ads from accessing the obligatory variables like `window`, `document` and the like by including a script that overwrites them prior to loading the ad. But be warned, there's always a possibility to get a hold on the actual window object somehow (I'll see if I can dig up the link where this is explained in detail).

Comment: Even mormons do XXX, I was told :D

Comment: Serving from subdomain.mormon.org leaves www.mormon.org safe from cross-site scripting (by default, unless you fiddle with `document.domain`). However subdomain.mormon.org can read cookies from mormon.org (so if you are running a site from a no-www hostname you might be vulnerable to session hijacking), and subdomain.mormon.org can set cookies that interfere with www.mormon.org's, which sometimes makes other security problems like inadequate CSRF protection exploitable. These are much less likely attacks than direct scripting into your document though.